# Why does `eq` not work when one argument has overloaded stringification?

Tags: perl, operator-overloading, stringification

I have realised (the hard way) that operator `eq` gives a fatal runtime error when one of the operand is an object with overloaded stringification.

Here is a minimal example:

```
my $test = MyTest->new('test');
print 'yes' if $test eq 'test';

package MyTest;

use overload '""' => sub { my $self = shift; return $self->{'str'} };

sub new {
    my ( $class, $str ) = @_;
    return bless { str => $str }, $class;
}
```

The result of running this is:

```
Operation "eq": no method found,
    left argument in overloaded package MyTest,
    right argument has no overloaded magic at ./test.pl line 7.
```

My expectation from reading [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) would be that string context is forced on both operands, firing the stringification method in `$test`, then the resulting strings are compared. Why doesn't it work? What is actually hapenning?

The context in which I had this problem was in a script that uses both `autodie` and `Try::Tiny`. In the `try` block, I `die` with some specific messages to be caught. But in the `catch` block, when I test for whether `$_ eq "my specific message\n"`, this gives a runtime if `$_` is an `autodie::exception`.

I know I will have to replace `$_ eq "..."` with `!ref && $_ eq "..."`, but I would like to know why.

Comment: try `"$test" eq 'test'`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, that worked, thanks. But I don't see what difference it makes to the interpreter!

Comment: `eq` comparison doesn't actually force `$test` to be stringified, it just use string compare on its arguments.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You only overloaded stringification, not string comparison. The `overload` pragma will however use the overloaded stringification for the string comparison if you specify the `fallback => 1` parameter:

```
my $test = MyTest->new('test');
print 'yes' if $test eq 'test';

package MyTest;

use overload
    fallback => 1,
    '""' => sub { my $self = shift; return $self->{'str'} };

sub new {
    my ( $class, $str ) = @_;
    return bless { str => $str }, $class;
}
```

Details on why this works:

When handed an overloaded object, the `eq` operator will try to invoke the `eq` overload. We did not provide an overload, and we didn't provide a `cmp` overload from which `eq` could be autogenerated. Therefore, Perl will issue that error.

With [`fallback => 1` enabled](http://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html#fallback), the error is suppressed and Perl will do what it would do anyway – coerce the arguments to strings (which invokes stringification overloading or other magic), and compare them.